MySQL flatten columns from the select subquery
I have the SQL statement to get back list of date and the corresponding rank of the player with the given date.
The idea here is to show the ranking progress of a player with the dates of the valid tournaments, as the date progress, the player can see the different of their ranking and points.
The problem is how can I flatten the other columns and display it together with the ranking? In this case, I want the SUM of points to show together with the rank.
SELECT `Date`,
    -- Select rank based on the date given
    (SELECT `ranking`.`Rank` FROM (SELECT 
    `c`.`PlayerId` AS `PlayerId`,
    SUM(`c0`.`Points`) AS `Points`,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(`c0`.`Points`) DESC) AS `Rank`
    FROM `CompetitionResultPlayer` AS `c` 
    INNER JOIN `CompetitionResults` AS `c0` ON `c`.`ResultId` = `c0`.`Id`
    INNER JOIN `Competitions` AS `c1` ON `c0`.`CompetitionId` = `c1`.`Id`
    INNER JOIN `Tournaments` AS `t` ON `c1`.`TournamentId` = `t`.`Id`
    WHERE (`c1`.`EventId` = 2) 
        AND `t`.`EndDate` BETWEEN CAST('2023-01-01' AS DateTime) AND CAST(`Date` AS DateTime) 
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM `RankingTournament` AS `r`
            WHERE (`t`.`Id` = `r`.`TournamentId`) AND (`r`.`RankingId` = 1))
    GROUP BY `c`.`PlayerId`) AS `ranking` WHERE `ranking`.`PlayerId` = 97751) AS `Rank`
    FROM 
    -- Get the dates that has changes for the ranking and event
    (SELECT DISTINCT EndDate AS `Date` 
    FROM `Competitions` AS `date_c`
    INNER JOIN `Tournaments` AS `date_t` ON `date_c`.`TournamentId` = `date_t`.`Id`
        WHERE (`date_c`.`EventId` = 2) 
        AND `date_t`.`EndDate` BETWEEN CAST('2023-01-01' AS DateTime) AND CAST('2023-12-2' AS DateTime) 
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM `RankingTournament` AS `date_r`
            WHERE (`date_t`.`Id` = `date_r`.`TournamentId`) AND (`date_r`.`RankingId` = 1))
            ) AS `Date`

The SQL result:



Date
Rank




2023-10-01 00:00:00.000000
1


2023-11-09 00:00:00.000000
3


2023-12-02 00:00:00.000000
9



As you can see, it show the dates of the ranking and event for a player as the ranking progress. I would like to have the points to display together with the rank but the subquery only allow to return only one column in this case.
Is there any better way to rewrite the query so it can get back the result with multiple columns from the ranking?
I have tried to use JOIN statement but end up with more confusion.
The expected result should be something like this:



Date
Rank
Points




2023-10-01 00:00:00.000000
1
800


2023-11-09 00:00:00.000000
3
800


2023-12-02 00:00:00.000000
9
800



As you can see, this player rank has drop over times as other player has gain more points than him.
I would like to also show the points which the points should also come from the ranking subquery.
Here is the the related sample data in other tables:
Rankings (This is where the user can choose different kind of ranking)



Id
Name




1
My First Ranking Test



RankingTournament (This is where the ranking contains some related tournaments, the ranking only show the tournaments that are in this junction table)



RankingId
TournamentId




1
138


1
139


1
140



Tournaments (The EndDate column is where the ranking changes based on)



Id
Name
EndDate




161
IM Sport Badminton Club Championship 2023
2023-10-01 00:00:00.000000


199
YONEX-SINGHA-QINGDAO JINYUAN-BTY Championships
2023-11-09 00:00:00.000000


203
test
2023-12-02 00:00:00.000000



Competitions (Here is where the Events (Like Boy Sinlge or Boy Double in badminton) bind with a tournament)



Id
TournamentId
EventId




2184
161
2


2185
199
2


2186
203
2



CompetitionResults (Here is where the tournament result will insert to, it contains points which is use to calculate the ranking)



Id
CompetitionId
Points




14432
2384
800



CompetitionResultPlayer (Here is where the players bind to a competition result as sometime the competition might have more than one player such as Boy Double category)



ResultId
PlayerId




14432
97751




Please provide some sample data and description of all the tables, explain logic and show the expected result with the data provided. Don't expect an answer to a question about your sql code Selecting  from 5 different tables we know nothing about. Yes, it is possible to make a close guess about the tables( using reverse engineering from your code ) but it is realy very bad to ask anybody to help you not providing the essential informations, and forcing them to make a blind guess about your specific data - it's just not polite, I'd say.

What is your MySQL Version? Maybe you can use CTE

And, yes, it is possible to get the result you need if you provide the data that the result is based on.

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Make it easy to help you!

@BusraEcemSakar They're using a window function, so it must be 8.x, which also has CTE.
